# Is it possible to read tables from a specific schema with sf::st_read_db()

Tags: postgis, postgresql, r, sf

How can I specify the schema from where to read a table in the `st_read_db()` function in the **sf** package in R?

When I try

```
require(RPostgreSQL)
require(sf)

drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con = dbConnect(drv, dbname = DBname_1, user = DBuser,
                host = DBhost, port = DBport, password = DBpassword)

dat = st_read_db(con, table = "schema1.table1",
      query = "SELECT * FROM schema1.table1 LIMIT 20")

dbDisconnect(con)
dbUnloadDriver(drv)
```

I get the error:

> Error: public.schema1.table1 does not exist.

It seems with this function I can only read tables from the public schema. Is this true or do I overlook something? Is this also maybe due to the early stage of the package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
dat <- st_read_db(con, table = c("schema1", "table1"),
                  query = "SELECT * FROM schema1.table1")
```

NB : here `query` is useless as you're selecting all rows

Comment: Thanks for the hint of putting the table information into a vector. However when I run your code it ignores the query argument. Note: I've changed the query to not represent the whole table.

Comment: And `dat <- st_read_db(con, query = "SELECT * FROM schema1.table1 LIMIT 20")` ?

Comment: returns the warning: `argument table missing: returning object without crs` but when I use `head(dat)` it shows me the right Multipolygons and I can plot 'em.. so it works.